# 'segmentation fault python' in Mac OS Big Sur with python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, anaconda, spyder, macos-big-sur

I am not totally sure if the problem started when upgrading to Big Sur:
I use anaconda distribution and when I use python 2.7 and plot (plot or scatter) using matplotlib, python closes and shows this message "zsh: segmentation fault  python" 
If instead I use Spyder 3 compiler, the message doesn't show up but neither the graph, it doesn't show anything at all.

The code can be as simple as:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
lx=[1,2]
ly=[1,2]
plt.scatter(lx,ly)
plt.show()
```

I have uninstalled all anaconda and installed again and now the message is: 
"Fontconfig warning: ignoring UTF-8: not a valid region tag 
zsh: segmentation fault  python"

This only happens with python 2.7, and I believe it started when making some updates on Big Sur OS.
When I open python 3.8 or 3.7 (or Spyder 4) there is no problem, all works fine.

Anaconda and Mac OS itself has recommended many times to upgrade to python 3.8, but I have worked so long with 2.7 and wish if I could stay some more time with my original codes and programs. \

I would like to know if this problem is because of the OS upgrade or if it is something else.

PD: I have updated matplotlib with Conda, everything looks updated (matplotlib: 2.2.3)
Also have uninstalled and reinstalled anaconda.
It doesn't work with python 2.7 on Big Sur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try uninstalling anaconda and running with the default python 2.7.16 that comes with Big Sur.

I had a similar segmentation issue just From `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`.

When I uninstalled anaconda the error solved.

Comment: It is right. It works with the included version of python 2.7 in Big Sur, but not with the Anaconda version for some reason. No need to uninstall. Thanks.